# Multiple proxy iteration with goutte - laravel

Tags: arrays, proxy, cron, laravel-5.4, goutte

I have array set of 10 proxies and set 2000 keywords to scrape the data .so i need to pass the 20 keywords per proxy IP , per hour for this i have setup the cron hourly basis i.e per hour 200 keywords with 10 random proxy from the array .proxy should not repeat in between in any hour.I am using the below code but its not giving the exact results.

```
$proxy = [
                    '0' => 'x.x.x.x:80',
                    '1' => 'x.x.x.x:80',
                    '2' => 'x.x.x.x:80',
                    '3' => 'x.x.x.x:80',
                    '4' => 'x.x.x.x:80',
                    '5' => 'x.x.x.x:80',
                    '6' => 'x.x.x.x:80',
                    '7' => 'x.x.x.x:80',
                    '8' => 'x.x.x.x:80',
                    '9' => 'x.x.x.x:80'
                ];

    foreach($proxy as $prox){

         $website[] = $prox[mt_rand(0, count($prox) - 1)];

         $keyword = keyword::take(20)->get();

         foreach($keyword as $list){


                //scraping code
                $client = new Client($website);

                $client->setAuth('xxx', 'xxx', 'basic');

                $client->setHeader('user-agent', "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.472.63 Safari/534.3");
                $crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
                $status = $client->getResponse()->getStatus();

                //store the data in database 
         }


    }
```

any suggestions would be appreciated  !

Comment: Hey! A little unsure what your issue is here. However, my suggestion would be to drop the proxy handling and use a service like https://www.proxicity.io. Their APIs would handle rotating the proxies and making sure that they are verified, etc, so you do not have to worry about it!

Comment: I m using the paid proxies .If i use one IP it works fine . if i run through array of IP's it's giving array like this way [error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809244/invalidargumentexception-the-current-node-list-is-empty)  . But not helping any answer i dont know what to do . If you have nay idea please let me know